# Google sheet | Conditional formatting | How to omit wildcard characters ?*

Tags: google-spreadsheets, wildcards

I was willing to create a conditional formatting that looks for ? signs in fields.
By default it functions as a wildcard character however. (As a replacement for "any" characters)

How to use it as true ? or * or ...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in here: 
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/09/07/google-sheets-conditional-formatting/

> For the question and asterisk characters not to be perceived as wildcard characters in your text values, a tilde (**~**) is usually added before them. E.g. the text rule that contains "Re?" in our example formats the cells with "Red", while the rule with "**Re~?**" won't find any cells as it will be looking for the value "**Re?**".